# Using abcwebmin.js - piano keys should move according to the notes in music xml

Tags: javascript, musicxml

I am using http://wim.vree.org/js/abcweb-min.js and referring to http://wim.vree.org/js/abcweb.html?pre_drum.
I also created a piano referring to codepen. I now need the piano keys to move according to the music notes. I have used a piano xml file for preload and the cursor moves as in the http://wim.vree.org/js/abcweb.html?pre_drum. link.But I couldn't find a way to handle the key notes.
I know this isn't a very straight question, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: *"I also created a piano."* - Please [edit] your question to show the relevant code. Where is your JS for the piano?

Comment: I created piano using https://codepen.io/moffboffjoe/pen/EjEYKg.